# ip_forward reverting back to 0 during ettercap subnet scanning

Tags: network, wireshark, sniffing, ettercap

Im trying to arp spoof a local network but the /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward is reverting back to 0 when ettercap is performing subnet scan on a network hub. Even if i change it back to 1 after the subnet scan wireshark doesn't seem to get all http data from the scanned hosts. Majority of the packets that wireshark intercepts are MDNS,ARP,OCSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the doc man ...

Based on the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ettercap):

> It has two main sniffing options:
>
> UNIFIED, this method sniffs all the packets that pass on the cable.
>   You can choose to put or not the interface in promisc mode (-p
>   option). The packet not directed to the host running ettercap will be
>   forwarded automatically using layer 3 routing. So you can use a mitm
>   attack launched from a different tool and let ettercap modify the
>   packets and forward them for you. The kernel ip_forwarding is always
>   disabled by ettercap. This is done to prevent to forward a packet
>   twice (one by ettercap and one by the kernel). This is an invasive
>   behaviour on gateways. So we recommend you to use ettercap on the
>   gateways ONLY with the UNOFFENSIVE MODE ENABLED. Since ettercap
>   listens only on one network interface, launching it on the gateway in
>   offensive mode will not allow packets to be rerouted back from the
>   second interface.

In short, depending on the mode used, ettercap disable ip forwarding since it forwards packets by itself.

I guess you're probably using the UNIFIED mode ...